OIDC/OAUTH api requests using different public clientId in an Angular app
An Angular (v17) application is made of different Angular elements which have to call different secured (bearer) APIs. The application is using "angular-oauth2-oidc" library from Manfred Steyer (https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc). The APIs are registered on the API Gateway with different OAUTH clientId from two different identity providers.
In short, the need is to be able to call APIs by specifying the IDP and the clientId. Probably best is to have those in a config.
All examples I found were using a unique configuration for the SPA.
What the best way to be able to do what I'm looking for?
I think that using hierarchical injectors in Angular isn't the best approach. I need something dynamic about the APIs, not the caller of the APIs
Issue posted on angular-oauth2-oidc: https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/issues/1437

You didn't ask a question.

Better that way?
